# Angular6 *ngIf doesnt load div section the first time the search button is clicked, instead loads on 2nd click

Tags: angular6, angular-ng-if, angular-material-6

Working on displaying and hiding a section using *ngIf, the div doesnt get activated on the first click of the button, but gets activated on the second.
Scenario - 
On entering a frame number and click of the search button a http call is made, the number received is checked against the status if it is true or false, if false the section should remain closed, meaning the data entered is wrong, if correct then data section will open and be patched with a few values. 
The below is the code at my component, where i am checking if the status from my response is true or false and displays notification once my status is fault.
Issue- though the condition is met of being true, my ngif section doesnt display, instead displays on the second click

```
onSubmitVehicleDetails() {
        console.log(this.vehdetails.status)
        console.log(this.fetch_vehicle);
        let formValue1: any = {
            chassis_no: this.vehicleDetailsForm.value.chassis_no,
        }
        this.policyService.getVehicleNumber(formValue1)
            .pipe()
            .subscribe(vehdetails => {
                this.displayModalPolicy(vehdetails),
                console.log(this.vehdetails.status)
if(this.vehdetails.status === false){ 
    this.fetch_vehicle = false;
            console.log(this.fetch_vehicle)

}
else {
    this.fetch_vehicle = true;
    console.log(this.fetch_vehicle)

}
                    console.log('vehdetails: ', vehdetails); //
                (error: any) => this.errorMessage = <any>error;
                console.log(this.vehdetails.status)

            }
            )
    }
    displayModalPolicy(vehdetails): void {
        this.vehdetails = vehdetails;

        this.vehicleDetailsForm.patchValue({
            model_name: vehdetails.data.model_name,
            v_fuel: vehdetails.data.v_fuel,
            v_yom: vehdetails.data.v_yom,
            v_cc: vehdetails.data.v_cc,
            variant_name: vehdetails.data.variant_name,
            exshow_price: vehdetails.data.exshow_price,
            engine_no: vehdetails.data.engine_no,
        });
        console.log(vehdetails);
        // the data on the form
        console.log(this.vehdetails.status)
        console.log(this.fetch_vehicle)

    }
```

This is the HTML

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="button"
                                        (click)="[onSubmitVehicleDetails()]">Search</button>
                                    <p>
                                        {{fetch_vehicle}}
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div *ngIf="fetch_vehicle">
                                <div class="form-group m-form__group row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <img src="assets/app/media/img/logos/logo-1.png">
                                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label">
                                            <h4>Vehicle Details</h4>
                                        </label>

                                    </div>
```

Comment: Not sure if it matters but you don't need [] around the click event.

Comment: @ajrthegreat, right had another function to be handled on the click event which i removed but missed removing the braces...